# An instrument I don’t recognize (photo included)

Tags: instruments, string-instruments

I’m not sure if this is a proper question to ask here so sorry in advance.

The other day I was in Barcelona and saw a guy playing a plucked string instrument that had the size of a viola.

Its body resembled a capsule in shape and its neck was cylindrical. I can’t remember how many strings it had but the timbre was quite round and the pitch was between that of a guitar and a bass. I attached a crude drawing based on my memory.[image]

Can someone maybe give me a hint on what it might be? It could be of Spanish or catalan origin.

Edit: Thanks for the comment! (I don’t have enough reputation to reply yet) I know this is quite an ambiguous question, but I remembered I had taken a photo of it:[image]

I don’t know if this makes the question clearer. Anyway, if it got voted down to -1 or below I will delete it.

Comment: Welcome. Like the pic., but feel that this kind of question isn't beat suited on this site. We'll see.

Comment: Hi! There's some difference of opinion on whether ["what kind of instrument is this](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2443/78419) should be on-topic here; in fact, it's mentioned as *not* covered [here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic). But even for those inclined to view this as on-topic, I'm afraid there just isn't enough to go on here. There are many, many plucked string instruments, even many with capsule-shaped bodies. If you can stumble across an actual photo, or tell more about the performance circumstances, you might have a better chance.

Comment: Btw, if this is off-topic as a question, there's a chat room here where you could still ask it. You need a reputation score of 20 to participate, but that's pretty easy to do.

Comment: I found this online but there is no information on the instrument itself, it is just part of a photo gallery. Scroll to image #13  https://www.madineurope.eu/en/trainings/escuela-de-violeria-de-zaragoza-manufacturing-of-spanish-guitar-plucked-and-bowed-string-instruments/

Comment: @JohnBelzaguy by opening that image in a new tab and viewing the filename, I could see that it is called a *Vihuela de arco*, a bowed instrument.  Searching for that led me to the Wikipedia article [Vielle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vielle).  Probably not the plucked, electrified instrument in the question photo.

Comment: @Theodore Perhaps not but it could also possibly be that same type of instrument being held like a guitar, amplified and plucked. The OP’s photo is very blurred but it does appear to show a violin/viola/cello style bridge,

Comment: @Theodore Upon looking more closely at your wiki article, the second picture shows 3 musicians, Two playing vielle and one playing citole, which looks similar and is played plucked in a guitar position. Maybe it is a modern version of that. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citole

Comment: Take a look at a Sintir/guembri some have circular necks

Comment: @Yorik I think we have a winner, you!

Comment: @Yorik I agree! One [photo on the Sintir page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sintir#/media/File:Nuru_Kane_Guimbri.jpg) on Wikiedia even shows an electrified version.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because instrument identification is off-topic.

Comment: @Dom - hardly just 'voting to close', but 'actually closing'. Had it been a question about a run of the mill instrument, I may have agreed, but I expect the vast majority of us have never seen one, let alone played one, or knew about tuning, etc. I have a feeling there should be room for this kind of question, without prejudice.

Comment: @Tim The trend on the site is identification questions about instrument are off-topic.  If we want there to be exceptions, we need to hash them out on meta so it doesn't seem arbitrary what we allow and what we don't.

Answer (score 2):

It's a *sintir*, *gimbri/guimbri/guembri*/*hajhuj*. Usually with three strings, top and bottom tuned one octave apart, the middle tuned to a fourth above the lowest, which is used as a drone. It seems it doesn't matter what notes - it's the intervals that are important.

The tuning method is unusual. No pegs, but cords wrapped around the neck (cylindrical), which slide up and down to tension the strings. The bridge is cambered, but nowhere near the radius of the neck. The soundboard is rather like a banjo - animal skin usually camel, so N.African generally.

The one pictured looks like a well adapted one, with a pup, probably piezzo, so the instrument can be amplified.